PY-PDE : define PDE with partial derivatives and solve it
I am trying to define and solve a PDE with partial derivatives and non-linear behavior using py-pde, unfortunately all the examples I found seem to use simple instruction like gradient and laplace, but not something more advanced such as this equation :

I tried using the following code, but the resolution doesn't seem to work, as the resulting state when displayed is exactly the initial condition:
import pde
grid = pde.CartesianGrid([[-3, 3]]*2, 100)

# Define the initial condition: 2D Gaussian with mean (1, 1) and covariance matrix 1/9
mean = np.array([1, 1])
cov = np.eye(2)/9
inv_cov = 9*np.eye(2)
norm_factor = 1 / (2 * np.pi * np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(cov)))

x1, x2 = grid.axes_coords
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(x1, x2, indexing='ij')
X = np.dstack((X1, X2))

initial_condition = norm_factor * np.exp(-0.5 * np.einsum('...i,ij,...j->...', X - mean, inv_cov, X - mean))
p0 = pde.ScalarField(grid, initial_condition)

# define the PDE
myPDE = pde.PDE({'p': '-x2 * diff(p,x1) + 0.2*p + (0.2*x2 + x1)*diff(p, x2) + 0.2*diff(p, x2, order = 2)'})
# solve the PDE
result = myPDE.solve(p0, t_range=5, dt=1e-3)


It’s parabolic in time, so solved by forward marching. In which case you could probably just use solve_ivp to solve it. By the way, how does your routine know that the LHS is dp/dt?

the py-pde library is written so that the LHS is always dp/dt. And from my understanding solve_ivp is for ODEs, not PDEs like my example

Actually, the _ivp bit in solve_ivp stands for “initial-value problem”, which is precisely what you have. It can advance an array of points forward in time just as well as a single variable.
